# Why cookie doesn't work using Sinatra and Omniauth?

Tags: session, cookies, sinatra, omniauth, rack

I need to change a cookie from "Session" type to "Persistent" type. Moreover I need to have it working together with "omniauth-facebook". In the example below everything is working well but when I use omniauth the cookie is not set at all. This is the test code I wrote:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'encrypted_cookie'
require 'omniauth-facebook'
use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie, :secret => "fdstopitot9dasdsdasjm4kmt0èu54cmjff83d2'ìel.4j9c"
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '290594154312564','a26bcf9d7e254db82566f31c9d72c94e'
end
get "/" do
  "persistent | session | /auth/facebook"
end
get "/persistent" do
  response.set_cookie 'test', {:value=> "persistent", :max_age => 2592000.to_s}
  redirect "/"
end
get "/session" do
  response.set_cookie 'test', {:value=> "session"}
  redirect "/"
end
get '/auth/:provider/callback' do
  response.set_cookie 'test', {:value=> "facebook_callback"}
  redirect "/"
end
```

Clicking on `/session` or `/persistent` you can see the cookie changing accordingly (in Chrome you can check cookies with F12 > Resources > Cookies > localhost).

Clicking instead on `/auth/facebook` the cookie is not set at all.

The response header seems ok (in Chrome you can see the http response header with F12 > Network > header). I only tested it with Chrome.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://localhost:4567/
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: test=facebook_callback
Set-Cookie: rack.session=X8U8kupLYzIurjMS4pSCQfF%2BzPpjQhJMqyMd84o8BQdQLwmhagL1UkZ4oi7%2F%0A9bEN%2B0FZDDUAeQD%2BRizczwvepQi%2FbcMwaAjpkFcXhiWuJPQ%3D%0A; path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
```

Any clue?

Comment: Is was a trivial problem, just add the path to the cookie:

response.set_cookie 'test', {:value=> "facebook_callback",  :path => "/"}

Should I remove the question?

Comment: You could post your answer and accept it; others may find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is was a trivial problem, just add the path to the cookie: response.set_cookie 'test', {:value=> "facebook_callback", :path => "/"}

The reason why I did not notice was that there is a redirect to "/", so Chrome was only showing me the cookies for the path "/". Removing the redirect, I notice I have two cookies named "test". One with "/" path and the other with "/auth" path.